# Utilizing C++ code in an Objective-C project

Tags: c++, objective-c

I've been learning C++ and SFML for quite a while now, and love the language and library, as it works well for me.  I've gotten interested in making iPhone apps, which I realize uses Objective-C.

Anyway, my question is, is there a way for me to call the use of C++ code (with SFML) in Objective C.  So while the program would work on an iPhone, the actual code is written mainly in C++?

Sorry if that's not.... descriptive enough, if you need more clarification, feel free to ask!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While you can easily use C++ code in an iOS project, there are no C++ versions of the iOS classes so you will probably end up with a lot of Objective-C rather than being able to code “mainly in C++”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact, you would probably use Objective-C++. Name your source files with the ".mm" extension instead of the ".m" extension, and the compiler will compile them as Objective-C++. There's even a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C%2B%2B#Objective-C.2B.2B) about it. You can also use regular C++ source files in your code and call them from Objective-C classes in this scenario. If you have more specific questions about it, feel free to ask.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the help.  So what about using an external library like SFML?  Would that cause any problems or possible obstacles?

Comment: When using Obj-C++, it's considered best practice to use it only to create an objective wrapper around what you're doing, then use Obj-C as much as possible.

Notice that Obj-C++ is denoted by its implementation extension (.m/.mm). If you create an Obj-C++ wrapper, you can still #import its interface from Obj-C. It's a common mistake to make everything in your project Obj-C++ just because one bit of code needs it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I assume inefficiency would get in the way.  Thanks to you both, my question is answered!